# Python function long parameter list

Tags: python, list, parameters, long-parameter-list

I'm looking for the best way to give a list of arguments to my function :

```
def myFunc(*args):
    retVal=[]
    for arg in args:
        retVal.append(arg+1)
    return "test",retVal
```

The problem is that it becomes very annoying when you have a long list of parameters to pass to your function because you have to write two times your whole list of parameters and When you have 10 parameters or more with complete names, it becomes really (really) heavy.

```
test,alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,iota=myFunc(alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,iota)
```

So I thought about something like this :

```
w=alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,iota
test,w=myFunc(w)
```

But then I sill have to do :

```
alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,iota=w
```

Is there any shorter way to give and get back a list of parameter from a function.
Or give a pointer to the function for it to modify directly the parameters ?

This is what I'm looking for :

```
w=alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,iota
test,w=myFunc(w)

# And directly get my parameters modified to be able to print them :
print alpha,[...],iota
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make the function return a dict. Then you can call it using `myFunc(**yourdict)` to use the dict items as arguments and if you `return yourdict` you get back the same dict (with probably modified values) - or you just modify the original dict and don't return one at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here is what I did following your idea :


`alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,iota=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

dict={'alpha':alpha,'beta':beta,'gamma':gamma,'delta':delta,'epsilon':epsilon,'zeta':zeta,'eta':eta,'theta':theta,'iota':iota}

dict=myFunc(**dict)

`


And this is my new function :


`def myFunc(**dict):
     retVal=[]
     for arg in dict:
         dict[arg]=dict[arg]+1
     return dict`


Thanks a lot !

Comment: 1. Don't use `dict` as a name for a dictionary, as this will override the actual class called `dict`. 2. You can define a dict using keywords like so: `d = dict(alpha=alpha, beta=beta, ...)` which will save you a lot of use of the shift key for quotes and colons.

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

1. Try reducing the number of arguments by splitting the logic into multiple functions.
2. If 1.) is not possible, you can use a dictionary a single argument - encapsulating all your arguments. This would be a flexible (signature of function stays the same, even if you take away or add parameters) and mostly readable solution (meaningful keys in the dictionary).

Comment: +1 for breaking up the function. A long parameter list is a [code smell](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html).